# Display a PDF in react-native-webview after fetch. iOS only

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to display a downloaded pdf inside a WebView. I'm using `react-native-webview` (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) and `rn-fetch-blob` to download it.

Basically i have a render that's just a WebView component:

```
if(this.state.path)
    return
        <WebView
            source={{ uri: this.state.path }}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
else return <Loader />
```

This component won't get rendered until the PDF is downloaded. After the download is complete i save the path into the state and show the WebView.

The PDF is downloaded correctly, i can manually go to the path i get in the state and open the PDF.

If i put the URL where i download the pdf from inside the uri like this (as example this is the google policy):

```
source = {{ uri : "https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/it//intl/it/policies/privacy/google_privacy_policy_it.pdf" }}
```

It works correctly and displays the pdf inside the `WebView`.

If i put my path to the pdf doing :

```
source = {{ uri : path/to/file.pdf}}
```

I get a blank screen.

Is there a way to display a file system pdf into the `WebView` ?

Note that i need to use the `WebView`, `react-native-pdf` and `react-native-pdf-view` are not the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries i found a solution that let me download the PDF trough a fetch and use the local path to display the PDF. Basically when downloading i had to give the saved file a path `.pdf` and add the props `useWebKit` and `originWhitelist`.

```
<WebView
    source={{ uri: this.state.path }}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    originWhitelist={["*"]}
    useWebKit
/>
```

When i fetched trough `rn-fetch-blob` I had to specify a path in the `fetchConfig` and use the `path` property.

```
path: path/to/download/dir/file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
source={require('path of your local html file')}
```

instead of

```
source = {{ uri : path/to/file.pdf}}
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTICE: On the iOS platform, the directory path will be changed every time you access the file system. So if you need to read the file on iOS, you need to get dir path first and concat file name with it.

```
let arr = fileResp.uri.split('file://');
        PATH_TO_THE_FILE = arr[1];
```

[Reference to Source](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#readfilepath-encodingpromise)